# excel/VBA: detect IE innertext fontweight

Tags: excel, vba, innertext

I need to detect if the fontweight of the selected innertext is bold. I just need a working syntax. Please help :(

Right now I'm using this but its not working:

```
If elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).fontWeight = 400 Then '<-- or "bold"
    MsgBox 1
End If
```

Edit:

I have a automation that will gather information in a carrier website. my code works and getting all necessary data. and now i'm on the next step of getting ONLY the Bold Text in the website. after hours of searching the net i have tried many syntax however none of them work. i just need to work with this line so i can proceed in my next step. :)

```
If elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).style.fontWeight = 400 Then '<-- or 
    "bold"
    'code here
End If
```

here is my code.

```
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
Sub extractTablesData()
Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, t As Integer
Dim elemCollection, elemClass As Object
Dim wb, twb As Workbook
Dim idStr As String
Dim ctr, RowCtr As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

DoEvents
For x = 2 To Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If Sheet2.Range("B" & x).Value <> "" Then
idStr = Sheet2.Range("B" & x).Value
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Sheet2.Range("A" & x & ":b" & x).Copy
Sheet3.Range("A" & Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
With IE
.Visible = True:
'added sample for your reference of the website
.navigate ("click the link"
```

[link](https://www.hapag-lloyd.com/en/online-business/tracing/tracing-by-container.html?container=CAIU++4802808)

```
DoEvents

While IE.readyState <> 4: Wend
Do While IE.readyState = 4 And Not IE.Busy
If IE.readyState = 4 Then
    Exit Do
End If
Sleep 100
DoEvents
Loop

Do While IE.readyState = 4 And Not IE.Busy
Sleep 100
DoEvents:
Loop

DoEvents

Sheet1.Range("A1:K500").ClearContents

Set elemCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("Table")

    For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)

        For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
            For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)

            MsgBox elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText


         If elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).fontWeight = 400 Then
                wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
                ctr = ctr + 1
           End If


Next c: Next r: Next t: End With: IE.Quit: Set IE = Nothing

Sheet1.Range("A3:F" & Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
Sheet3.Range("C" & Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
If ctr <> 0 Then
    Sheet3.Range("A" & Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row & ":B" & Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    Sheet3.Range("A" & Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row & ":B" & Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End If
ctr = 0: Z = 0:
End If
Next:

End Sub
```

Comment: hi and welcome to SO, consider making the [tour] first and make sure to also read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: You need to look at the properties of the cell's `style` object.   Also your question needs more details: show more of your code, include the relevant HTML, and describe any errors you're getting.

Comment: I fixed the formatting of the code and capitalized the sentences.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. ive updated my query.

Comment: I can't view the URL. Please can you share the relevant HTML. If possible also https://pastebin.com/ the entire html refacting any confidential info. If you are targeting the font-weight CSS property you cannot do that with CSS selectors. Your best bet is to see if there is actually another identifier such as class (maybe with position) that can be used to identify these elements.  As a last resort you could use a regex. We need to see some HTML inserted using snippet tool via [edit] (i.e. not as an image please).

Comment: [link](https://www.hapag-lloyd.com/en/online-business/tracing/tracing-by-container.html?container=CAIU++4802808) try this to view.. as i dont have pastebin.com access in my network right now.

Comment: `fontWeight` is not a numeric style attribute - you should be checking for "bold" not 400...

Comment: ...or check the class name for each cell - looks like bolded cells have "strong" as a classname.

Comment: @tim williams yes all bold has strong tags however i dont know how or what is the syntax to detect does strong tags

Comment: Something like `If elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).getattribute("className") = "strong" Then`